Reassigning a global variable in JavaScript using an event listener
Apologies but I'm fairly new to JS - i'm attempting to assign "humanChoice" using event listeners and then use that value in the function playRound. However, when I print it to the log, the value is returning as undefined although I'm attempting to assign it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
let humanChoice

rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    humanChoice = "rock"
    playRound()
});

function playRound(humanChoice, computerChoice) {

    if (humanChoice === computerChoice) {
        console.log("It's a tie! There is no winner this round.")
    } else if (humanChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "paper") {
        computerScore++
        console.log("You lose! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    } else if (humanChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
        humanScore++
        console.log("You win! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    } else if (humanChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "rock") {
        humanScore++
        console.log("You win! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    } else if (humanChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
        computerScore++
        console.log("You lose! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    } else if (humanChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "paper") {
        humanScore++
        console.log("You win! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    } else if (humanChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "rock") {
        computerScore++
        console.log("You lose! Your score is " + humanScore + " and the computer's score is " + computerScore + ".")
    }
}

I would expect humanChoice to be reassigned to "rock", and allow me to pass it in to playRound. However, it returns undefined.

Try using a function() {} handler instead of a fat arrow handler; the fat arrow binds to the containing scope, which in this case I believe might be the scope of the element, and not the window object.

@Daedalus I tried
    humanChoice = "rock"
    playRound()
});

With the same result unfortunately. Hmm

You should not define any parameters in function playRound if you're not passing any, since humanChoice and computerChoice are already defined as global variables. Otherwise they will be shadowed by the local variables due to the same names. Define it like function playRound() { /* ... */ } instead

See variable shadowing.
You defined a local variable humanChoice as parameter in playRound but did not pass any value when you call it. There is two solutions as below.
Pass as local variable.
// let humanChoice

rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // humanChoice = "rock"
    playRound('rock') // pass 'rock' as parameter
});

function playRound(humanChoice) { // use local variable humanChoice
    // ...
}

Or use global variable
let humanChoice

rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    humanChoice = "rock"
    playRound()
});

function playRound() { // remove local variable humanChoice
    // use global variable humanChoice
}


computerChoice will be undefined if you're not passing any parameter when calling playRound()

@HaoWu you are right. it can do same operation with computerChoice.

@user24924388 thank you so much... this worked and really cleared things up! Thanks!
